# Copy tables selected from sys.tables to new DB

Tags: sql-server

**Note:-** I have a Database(DB) with Thousands of Tables.

I want to Copy all Tables with Name like `'TableType1%'` to a new Database(DB).

I can easily get a list of the tables:

```
select * from sys.tables t
where schema_name(t.schema_id) = 'S1' AND [name] LIKE 'TableType1%'
```

> But how do I copy them to a new Database(DB)?

I CANNOT do this manually, as there are too many Tables.

**I would like to use**

```
INSERT INTO....
```

Type statement, but don't know how to put it into Select Statement above.

Comment: Copy what? The structures? The data? Both? Need more info.

Comment: Why not use the data migration assistant in SSMS?

Comment: Or restore a copy of the database and drop all the tables you don't want.

Comment: I want to copy the structure and data

Comment: I agree with @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, this would be thing to do...

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft That is not workable, as I would need to drop thousands of table manually

Comment: It is easier to automate the drop of tables than the creation of tables. You would just have to copy the whole database and then create `DROP TABLE`  statements for all tables which do **not** match your criteria.

Comment: The DB is quite large (40G) so I would have trouble restoring that.

Comment: 40G is nothing for a modern database or disc. It will only take maybe 10-15 minutes to restore the database. You could then easily utilize sys.tables to generate a bunch of drop statements for the tables you don't want. And this would be one of those rare times where truncating the log after would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * into DestinationDB from SourceDB.sys.tables where name like 'TableType1%'
```

Note:- In database (DestinationDB)  the physical tables are created with same name in source databse (SourceDB)